# How to make a boolean both static and __block? in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, static-variables

```
bool _hintExist;
- (void)showNotReachable
{
    if (_hintExist) {
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Show a hint");

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _hintExist = NO;
    });
}
```

The code above is fine. There is a button to trigger the method. Actually, I don't need _hintExist be a global variable. I want to make bool _hintExist in the method.However, when I tried to add both static and __block in front of bool _hintExist. There would be a compile error. I was amazed that I could change _hintExist in the block if I made it a global variable. Could someone explain why? And what's the difference if I add static before bool _notReachableHintExist, the global variable in my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__block` is essentially a scope modifier to a local variable that allows a block to modify the value of the local variable declared in the outer scope.

Your `_hintExist` variable isn't a local variable. It's a global. So there is no need for the `__block` modifier. The block has access to a global variable just like any other piece of code in the same file.

If you simply add `static` to your `_hintExist` variable, it is still a global but it is now scoped to just this file. And the block, like any other code in the file, can still access and modify the file global variable.

Another option is to make the `_hintExist` variable a local static variable like this:

```
- (void)showNotReachable
{
    static bool _hintExist = false;

    if (_hintExist) {
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Show a hint");

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _hintExist = NO;
    });
}
```

This works as well assuming it is what you want. The variable is scoped only to the method but being static means the value is independent of any specific instance of the class. Again, being `static` means you don't need the `__block` modifier. It's like a global but only inside the method.

BTW - a minor note on common naming conventions. Don't use a leading underscore for variables except for instance variables.

Update based on Andy's second comment below this answer:

It seems you actually want to use an instance variable since you want each instance of your class to start with its own `false` value for `_hintExist`.

Add the ivar to the `@implementation` block:

```
@implementation WhateverClassThisIs {
    bool _hintExist;
}
```

And the updated `showNotReachable` method:

```
- (void)showNotReachable
{
    if (_hintExist) {
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"Show a hint");

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        _hintExist = NO;
    });
}
```

Like the globals and statics, the instance variable doesn't need the `__block` qualifier. And, by default, `_hintExist` will have an initial value of `false`.

Comment: Thank you. If I simply add static to my _hintExist variable, it is still a global but it is now scoped to just this file. What do you mean scoped to just this file? Other files cannot get _hintExist anyway. By the way, I use underscore to mean global, how do you do to mean global?

Comment: Oh, static bool _hintExist = false; This doesn't solve my problem. If I dealloc the ViewController and init ViewController again in 3 seconds. _hintExist is still true. When I init the ViewContoller again, I hope _hintExist = false.

Comment: If using a method local `static` doesn't meet your needs then using the global as you originally had it wouldn't have met your need either. They would have worked the same except for the change in scope. From your latest description, you want to use an ordinary instance variable. I've update my answer to reflect this.